# Java JMenu setAccelerator() problem

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

When I set setAccelerator() to Control + A or Control + P and I run the program it doesn't detect the keystroke.

Here's the code:

```
  menuItem = new JMenuItem("About");
  menuItem.setActionCommand("About");
  menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK));
  menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  menuItem.addActionListener(this);
  menu.add(menuItem);
```

Then when it's pressed it should invoke the Action Listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("About")) {

   System.out.println("About");

  }
}
```

I'm running it in Eclipse on a Mac if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

Control-A and Control-P are both keystrokes that may already be intercepted, depending on your platform and depending on what has keyboard focus.  Control-A may already be intercepted and interpreted as "select all", and Control-P may already be intercepted and interpreted as "paste".

What if you select a less commonly-used keystroke instead of "Control-A", such as "Control-Shift-A" or "Control-B"?  Here's a modified version of your code that uses Control-Shift-A instead of Control-A:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("About");
menuItem.setActionCommand("About");
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK | Event.SHIFT_MASK));
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
menuItem.addActionListener(this);
menu.add(menuItem);
```

I tested this change on my own system using [the JMenu demo from the Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#MenuDemo), and I found (exactly as you did) that registering Control-A as the accelerator had no effect.  However, registering Control-Shift-A as the accelerator worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if it will help, but you're using `Event.CTRL_MASK` instead of `KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK`